# How Caching can be done in Canvas Apps PoweApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection

I am stuck with a problem to implement **Caching** in **Canvas Apps PowerApps**, but I am unable to find an apt solution for this and not even confirm if it is possible or not? Please help!!

I tried using **Collections** but still I'm unable to achieve caching using this approach.

Comment: I've done some work with offline, which uses Collections for caching.  What were the problems you had using Collections?

Comment: Hi @HSS , is it possible if we can implement cache functionality in a canvas app? I just wanted to know how to utilize collections to achieve caching, and btw what's your approach to it. Thanks

Comment: Offline can be done but there is a fair bit of "coding" involved.  This is a good starting point - https://joyofpowerapps.com/2021/04/14/an-honest-guide-to-canvas-app-offline-part-1/

Comment: Oh Great, it'll meet my requirements then? like if I apply the concept of taking an app offline, then caching can be achieved. right? @HSS

Comment: Yes.  It can definitely be done.  Just be careful when making estimates to complete the app - it adds a lot of complexity as any data used in the app will be in the Collections.

Comment: Okay Sure I'll take care of that @HSS Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build offline capable canvas Power Apps then it is supported by Microsoft Power Apps.

You have to use SaveData, LoadData, and ClearData functions in Power Apps for such requirements.

Check below documentations for detailed information:

1. [SaveData, LoadData, and ClearData functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-savedata-loaddata)
2. [Develop offline-capable canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/offline-apps)